# In Scala, What is the easiest way to interleave large number of iterators?

Tags: scala, iterator

Assuming that I have a number of iterators with identical arities:

```
val i1, i2, ..., in: Iterator[T]
```

Now I want to interleave them into a big iterator:

```
val cc: Iterator[Seq[T]]
```

where:

```
cc(x)(1) = Seq(i1(x), i2(x), ... in(x))
```

and cc.next() triggers the next to be called on all its element.

What's the easiest way of doing this?

I've tried recursively zipping them (which causes high object overhead), or use .transpose() which destroy it's efficiency as an iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own iterator and define how it's `next` and `hasNext` works according to your desired logic. This assumes iterators are of the same arity as you specified:

```
class MyIterator[T](iterators: List[Iterator[T]]) extends Iterator[List[T]] {
    def hasNext = iterators.headOption.map(_.hasNext).getOrElse(false)
    def next = iterators.map(_.next)
}

val iterators = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9)).map(_.toIterator)
iterators: List[Iterator[Int]] = List(non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator, non-empty iterator)

val it = new MyIterator(iterators)
```

Test:

```
while(it.hasNext)
    println(it.next)
```

Prints:

```
List(1, 4, 7)
List(2, 5, 8)
List(3, 6, 9)
```